# How to get rid of array appending python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, row

Hi have an a vector that looks like:

```
[array([ -99.21898 , -200.566483,    0.58519 ]), array([-1.00395332e+02, -2.05700867e+02,  6.47600000e-02]), array([-9.99833530e+01, -2.00824783e+02,  6.77800000e-02]), array([ -99.951599, -200.833435,    0.52976 ]), array([-100.375549, -205.394653,    0.58454 ]), array([-100.453751, -205.939728,    0.58379 ]), array([ -99.921898, -200.566483,    0.58519 ])]
```

I want to get rid of that and make it into a proper 7x3 matrix, how do I do that

Comment: Are you referring to numpy arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a length 7 list containing arrays of size 3. You can just pass exactly what you have into np.array() to create a 7x3 array.